# select value contain specific string for new columns

Tags: r, string, tidyverse

For example, I have a `df` as below, and I want to make a new column with specific `string`

```
df <- data.frame(name1 = c("Amydrium sp. 01", "Aporosa sp.", "Arecaceae sp. 02","Adenia macrophylla"))
             name1
1  Amydrium sp. 01
2      Aporosa sp.
3 Arecaceae sp. 02
4 Adenia macrophylla
```

I would like to have 2 additional columns called `family` and `genus`

I can make the `family` column by detect `ceae` string (i.e. `df %>% mutate(family = case_when(str_detect(name1, "ceae") ~ name1))`.

For `genus` column can I get a syntax as detect `sp.`exclude `ceae`, and dont want to to with several cell having full name i.e. `Adenia macrophyll` same time to get the column?.

-Desired output

```
             name1    family              genus
1  Amydrium sp. 01    NA                 Amydrium sp. 01
2      Aporosa sp.    NA                 Aporosa sp.
3 Arecaceae sp. 02    Arecaceae sp. 02   NA
4 Adenia macrophylla  NA                 NA
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do the opposite and also look for `sp.`:

```
df %>%
  mutate(
      family = case_when(str_detect(name1, "ceae")  ~ name1),
      genus  = case_when((!str_detect(name1, "ceae") & str_detect(name1, "sp.")) ~ name1)
  )
```

Output:

```
               name1           family           genus
1    Amydrium sp. 01             <NA> Amydrium sp. 01
2        Aporosa sp.             <NA>     Aporosa sp.
3   Arecaceae sp. 02 Arecaceae sp. 02            <NA>
4 Adenia macrophylla             <NA>            <NA>
```

Comment: I just editted my question

Comment: @Anh Edited my answer :)

Comment: is that possible if I want to do it with `case_when` ?

Comment: @Anh It's already using `case_when`...

Comment: oh yeah sorry :D. Thank you, I not looked at carefully :)))))